# webView in android open the website in web instead of webview

Tags: android, webview

when I run this code, "google.com" open in web application (for examaple google chrome) and not in the webView in the dialog.
It's does work OK with some urls.
Why?

```
    final Dialog dialog=new Dialog(this.activity,android.R.style.Theme_Black_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);

    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.full_page_ad_between_chapters);
    WebView webView = (WebView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl("http://google.com");
```

R.layout.full_page_ad_between_chapters :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="350dp"
    android:layout_height="1000dp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/fullPageAdBetweenChaptersClose"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="סגור" />

        <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to override the method [shouldOverrideUrlLoading()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29) on your [WebViewClient](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html).

```
WebView webView = (WebView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.webView1);
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        // check if we want to open the url into the WebView
        if (iWantToOpenTheUrlIntoTheWebView(url)) {
            return false;
        }
        // let the system handle the url outside of the app
        return true;
    }
});
```